# mock a request in postman

Tags: mocking, postman, postman-testcase, mockserver

I am trying to mock the server on Postman with a specific type of request.

request format

GET : /v1/employee/{empID}

here empID is dynamic but still want to mock this irrespective of empID. I need to have the same response (like some dummy data) for any empID.

Comment: You should check out Postman docs on Mocking a server https://learning.postman.com/docs/designing-and-developing-your-api/mocking-data/setting-up-mock/#mock-server-quick-start